# Ruby equivalent of ActiveRecord 'where'

Tags: ruby, where-clause

I have an array, and I want to filter for example by :city. Using ActiveRecord query it would be something like this:

```
MyBase.where(city: "NY")
```

How can I filter an array without ActiveRecord method, using only pure Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method.

```
array_of_objects.select { |o| o.city == "NY" }
```

Example :

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :city)

array_of_persons = [ Person.new('A', 'foo'), Person.new('B', 'boo') ]
array_of_persons.select { |person| person.city == 'foo' }
# => [#<struct Person name="A", city="foo">]
```